# ExoPlayer AudioProcessor is delayed

Tags: android, audio, java-native-interface, exoplayer

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to implement a c++ based audio effect into exoplayer using their `AudioProcessor` interface. I already have an attempt to fix my issue (described below) by decreasing output buffer size. I have a related question posted here: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/6216

My problem is that my audio effect (rough implementation to be seen here: https://gist.github.com/l0rn/30b9f846f869e55e1b0c6cb241e19114) needs to start processing quickly after the user enables it from a button in the app. At the moment it takes between 200 and 700ms to do so. My guess is, that there is still some unprocessed audio in the output buffer that needs to be flushed until the processed audio follows.

So basically i'm searching for options how to resolve this issue and appreciate any help

Comment: Hey, could you provide a code snippet of how exactly you're doing the switch on the fly? I want to implement the ChannelMappingAudioProcessor but I don't know how I am supposed to change the mapping at runtime. You can define the renderers with processors while creating the instance of ExoPlayer, but after the creation there is no access to them, so how did you do it?

Comment: I asked the question officially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57688372/how-to-modify-audio-processors-on-the-fly) 
I will be grateful if you could answer it